# How can I change my global user.name in Git? Note: I had already specified the global username and email using config

Tags: git, github

I had first set only my first name as my global username then I tried to change it and set my full name. In order to do that I tried config command but it shows error : [See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSA4e.png)

Then I used --replace-all command to do that but my username changed to "--replace-all" : [See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TE06g.png)

How can I change this now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of `--replace-all` matters in this case. Have you tried it like this?

`git config --global --replace-all user.name "Apar Agarwal"`